# Excluding one row from a ManytoMany relationship in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

This is my User object,

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    mobile = PhoneNumberField(null=True)
    username = models.CharField(null=False, unique=True, max_length=255)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

And this is my Quiz object,

```
class Quiz(Base):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='quizzes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    players = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

This is the filter that I'm using to find quizzes of a particular category that the user has not played,

```
quiz = Quiz.objects.filter(category=category).exclude(players=user).order_by('created')[:1]
```

But the exclude is a list and thus doesn't work. How do I correctly frame this query to exclude the current user?

Comment: What do you mean "*the exclude is a list*"?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem players in Quiz is a list, my question is how do I write the exclude statetement to check that one user is not on that list.

Comment: exactly one of the list, one or more, all?

Comment: Exactly one user, should not be on the list of players.

Comment: But the list thus contains multiple users, right?

Comment: Yes that's exactly the problem I'm trying to address, how do I exclude one user from a list of many users.

Comment: So to summarize, you have a list of users `[u1, u2, u3]` for example, and you want to exclude Quizes where only `u1` participated in, and quizes where only `u2` participated in, and quizes where only `u3` participated in (well in those quizes there can be other participants, but not `u1`, `u2`, `u3`).

Comment: Yes precisely that's what I'm trying to find.

Answer (score 1):

This answer aims to answer the *following* problem (since it is rather complicated, I want to make sure that it matches exactly):

> "*A queryset that contains `Quiz`zes where we exclude the `Quiz`zes hat have* exactly one *participant in the list of `users`*". So those quizzes are *not* part of the queryset.

I would each time count the number of overlaps, and then exclude the `Quiz`zes where the number of overlap is equal to zero. Something like:

```
Quiz.objects.filter(
    Q(players__in=users) | Q(players__isnull=True)
).annotate(
    overlap_size=Count('players')
).exclude(overlap_size=1)
```

We thus always calculate the "*overlap*": the number of users that are *both* in your list of `users`, and in the list of the participants. Then we this exclude the `Quiz`zes where that overlap is exactly one, hence quizes where there was exactly *one* participant that was in the `users` list.

In case you want quizzes where the overlap is exactly one, you only have to replace the `.exclude(..)` (at the end) with a `.filter(..)` instead.

Comment: So I dont want to exclude one(as in any) user but a specific user U1.

Comment: But then `user` is *not* a list? Perhaps it is better if you edit your question with some sample quizzes, to emonstrate what the query is supposed to do.

Comment: so players is the list of users who've played the quiz, but user is a specific user whom I want to exclude because he's already played the quiz. Does this clarify?

Comment: You want to exclude the `Quiz`zes where the `user` has already played in? Well then the query in your question solves the problem.

Comment: I don't think it does, user is a row and players are multiple users. I want to determine that the user is not in the list. I don't think my query does that.

Comment: Yes, it does, the filtering works over this many to many, and will thus check if the `user` is *among* the participants, and if that is the case, you `.exclude(..)` the quiz. If you run the query, what is *not* working?